Duplicate Subtree in a Binary tree Time and space complexity
I saw the following question on GFG to find if there's a duplicate subtree of size 2 or more in a binary tree.
Now, it is written in the practice question requirements and also articles everywhere say that TC and Space complexity are both O(N) here, but I think it's O(N^2) since "subtrees" here is an std::unordered_set of size N in worst case and each element in the worst case can have size N (not all will have size N, but even then space comes to be O(N^2)).  Also, since string concatenation is O(N), the time complexity also seems like O(N^2).
I can understand somehow if we could do concatenation in O(1) with modern compliers or using std::vector<char> but space definitely seems like O(N^2) to me. Am I understanding something wrong here?
// C++ program to find if there is a duplicate
// sub-tree of size 2 or more.
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Separator node
const char MARKER = '$';

// Structure for a binary tree node
struct Node {
    char key;
    Node *left, *right;
};

// A utility function to create a new node
Node* newNode(char key)
{
    Node* node = new Node;
    node->key = key;
    node->left = node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

unordered_set<string> subtrees;

// This function returns empty string if tree
// contains a duplicate subtree of size 2 or more.
string dupSubUtil(Node* root)
{
    string s = "";

    // If current node is NULL, return marker
    if (root == NULL)
        return s + MARKER;

    // If left subtree has a duplicate subtree.
    string lStr = dupSubUtil(root->left);
    if (lStr.compare(s) == 0)
        return s;

    // Do same for right subtree
    string rStr = dupSubUtil(root->right);
    if (rStr.compare(s) == 0)
        return s;

    // Serialize current subtree
    s = s + root->key + lStr + rStr;

    // If current subtree already exists in hash
    // table. [Note that size of a serialized tree
    // with single node is 3 as it has two marker
    // nodes.
    if (s.length() > 3
        && subtrees.find(s) != subtrees.end())
        return "";

    subtrees.insert(s);

    return s;
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    Node* root = newNode('A');
    root->left = newNode('B');
    root->right = newNode('C');
    root->left->left = newNode('D');
    root->left->right = newNode('E');
    root->right->right = newNode('B');
    root->right->right->right = newNode('E');
    root->right->right->left = newNode('D');

    string str = dupSubUtil(root);

    (str.compare("") == 0) ? cout << " Yes "
                           : cout << " No ";
    return 0;
}


This has nothing to do with C++, it is a pure algorithm question. The code you show is also of dubious quality (#include <bits/stdc++.h> <-- not standard C++, using namespace std; not recommended, NULL instead of nullptr, new instead of std::make_unique)... so whatever source you pulled this from... don't trust it to learn C++ from. And... copying N elements is always O(n), the tree has nothing to do with it.

It is strongly recommended not to include headers that are for internal use only in a library. Indeed, <bits/stdc++> is not a standard C++ header, and therefore it is not possible to ensure that the code will work on another platform. Furthermore, the compare() member function of the std::basic_string container can be replaced, in this case, with the overloaded operator==().

I saw the following question on GFG -- What is "GFG"?  Contrary to popular belief, few C++ programmers know what "GFG" is.  If you are referring to that site that supposedly teaches C++, it is a garbage site with garbage code examples.

@PepijnKramer thanks. I really didnt know these things since I've always been using geeksforgeeks and the code always works with that on it. Anyhow, would you reckon space complexity here is O(N) or O(N^2)?

GeeksForGeeks is really a low quality source for anything related to C++. You really should be using cppreference and read the C++ core guidelines and then compare it to everything you've read on GeeksForGeeks.

Big O doesn't care about the steps needed for a single node. In theory each node could take one hour to copy (very slow string concatenation) as long as making one copy of a node doesn't rely on the number of nodes it does not affect the order.

@PepijnKramer but then the longest possible string in set "subtrees" would be N, and it can have at max N/2 values (in a balanced binary tree, since leaf node trees aren't in the set), that's why I thought space here is O(N^2).

You are correct: The code is not O(n).
It’s playing an algorithmic complexity shell game with you.

So where did it go?
While the code makes an ostensive O(n) pass over the tree, that is only because it uses a hash map to cheat — by offloading the re-searching into a string compare.
Notice that little subtrees.find(s) there near the bottom? Yep. There’s your missing O(n·logn). For every node O(n) we search through all the other found nodes O(logn+s(n)) for a match.
But wait, there’s more!
Not only is the hash map storing every (unique) node tree, it is storing every complete set of (unique) subtrees! This explosively duplicates information to more than the O(n) space requirements of the original tree!
⟶ Remember Big-O observes the worst-case scenario.
So, for every node, it store the complete subtree in the hash map. That’s O(n·logn) as well.
⟶ If getting picky with data structure: the space requirements for a variable-length string is not constant. But even in the case of a small tree like this example and string size optimizations, a C++ string class is still larger than the original struct Node, making it at best an Ω(1<k<logn) space complexity.

Observations
Let us take a look at what the author did. Evidently the idea was to use a hash map to reduce (key ⟶ node) lookup to O(1), but that was as far ahead as the author thought.
The example tree given is (A (B D E) (C () (B D E))). If we print out the subtrees hash map on that we get:
  BD$$E$$
  E$$
  D$$

...which doesn’t look too bad (we don’t see E$$ repeated twice in the map), but we should already observe the aforementioned flaw here. Notice how E$$ and D$$ are repeated in BD$$E$$?
Let’s change the tree to (A (B D E) (C () (Q R S))) (no duplicate subtrees) and run the algorithm and again print out the subtrees hash map:
  ABD$$E$$C$QS$$R$$
  R$$
  QS$$R$$
  S$$
  C$QS$$R$$
  BD$$E$$
  E$$
  D$$

Yikes! It appears that using a hash map didn’t really help here. (At least not the way it was used.)
⟶ The very first line of this output would be O(n)

Final complexity
Looks like O(n·logn) for both time and space. And using the hashmap only improves the space complexity in a best-case scenario (which the author supplied. Sneaky no?).
⟶ An even better space scenario is (A (A A A) (B () (A A A))). Try it!
Design & Analysis of Algorithms really is not the easiest thing to master. (And I am no master. I could be totally wrong here. If I am, I’m sure to be eaten alive by others better at this than I am here on SO.) D&A is, factually, one of the toughest things about CS. (And is a University-level course worthy of taking multiple times.)
I totally want to sit on my hands before posting this, because I still have the sneaking feeling I missed something important, lol.
